# Recommended approach for retrieving rotating RDS credentials stored in Secrets Manager for python web app?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, aws-secrets-manager

I have a `flask` app running on `ECS` with `EC2 instance type` that accesses a `RDS` database. I'm storing the database credentials in `Secrets Manager`. I'd like to enable the built-in rotation provided by `Secrets Manager`, but I'm unsure about the best way to approach it.

I don't want to poll `Secrets Manager` for the credentials every time I need to make a request because of the cost. I also can't hard-code the credentials with a single call to `Secrets Manager` to use for the lifecycle of the app since the credentials will eventually be rotated.

Thoughts I have are to use a caching mechanism and a background task that polls `Secrets Manager` for changes in `Secrets Manager` credentials at a fixed interval. This still seems costly to me though since you're constantly polling `Secrets Manager`. The other issue is if the credentials are rotated between the fixed interval then they will be invalid until the background task runs again. I then have to worry about securing the credentials in the cache as well.

My other thought is to have an CloudWatch event tied to when `Secrets Manager` rotates the credentials. However, I'm having a hard time on how to trigger an event in my running `flask` app on `ECS` to update the credentials from `Secrets Manager`.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Using a CloudWatch event to trigger an update of the credentials upon their rotation in the Secrets Manager seems like a solution in your case.</s>

You can create a Lambda function that listens to the Secrets Manager rotation event and then updates the cached credentials in your Flask app. For example, you could use Redis to cache the credentials for your app.

You'll have something along these lines in your Lambda:

```py
import boto3
import redis
import json


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    secret_arn = event['detail']['SecretId']
    if 'previousSecretVersionId' in event['detail']:
        previous_secret_version_id = event['detail']['previousSecretVersionId']
    else:
        previous_secret_version_id = None

    if 'versionId' in event['detail']:
        current_secret_version_id = event['detail']['versionId']
    else:
        current_secret_version_id = None

    if previous_secret_version_id and current_secret_version_id:
        client = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
        response = client.get_secret_value(SecretId=secret_arn, VersionId=current_secret_version_id)
        secrets = json.loads(response['SecretString'])
        
        # Update the cached credentials here
        redis_client = redis.Redis(host='<redis_endpoint>', port=6379, db=0, password='<redis_password>')
        redis_client.set('DB_USERNAME', secrets['username'])
        redis_client.set('DB_PASSWORD', secrets['password'])
    else:
        print('Rotation event is missing `previousSecretVersionId` or current `versionId` ID.')
```

**UPDATE:** Instead of creating a Lambda to listen for a credentials rotation, you should create a Lambda that will be handling the rotation based on a specific schedule. While in your Flask app you should be retrieving the credentials from the AWS `SecretCache` (https://github.com/aws/aws-secretsmanager-caching-python) to reduce the cost of Secrets Manager API requests:

```py
import botocore 
import botocore.session 
from aws_secretsmanager_caching import SecretCache, SecretCacheConfig 

client = botocore.session.get_session().create_client('secretsmanager')
cache_config = SecretCacheConfig()
cache = SecretCache(config = cache_config, client = client)

secret = cache.get_secret_string('mysecret')
```

The rotation Lambda will do the following:

1. Create a new version of the secret
2. Change the credentials in the database or service
3. Test the new secret version
4. Finish the rotation

[Here's](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-secrets-manager-rotation-lambdas/blob/master/SecretsManagerRDSPostgreSQLRotationSingleUser/lambda_function.py) a Lambda function template for updating an RDS PostgreSQL user credential.

**References:**

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_cache-python.html

Comment: That makes sense. You have to have an external cache that doesn't site inside the `flask` app in order to allow updates to the cache from a `CloudWatch` event, while also allowing the `flask` app to poll the cache for every request to `RDS` to ensure credentials are always up to date.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I added that to the answer as an update.

Comment: So you would be running the lambda function on every read/write to the RDS database then, correct? My concern then would be the lambda cost if I have a large number of RDS requests happening per day.

Comment: Not quite. You need to configure your Lambda function to listen to a CloudWatch event, that's just a trigger that will tell AWS to automatically invoke the Lambda function once a specific CloudWatch event occurs.
You don't have to pay extra for setting up a CloudWatch event to trigger a Lambda function. You pay for the Lambda runs only.

Comment: You're right, I was mistakenly thinking running the lambda function on a schedule. Great, this solution should work. I then only have two concerns left. First would be the cost of the `Redis` cluster, with the cheapest being $3 per month. It's a little pricey to manage a single `RDS` instance credentials. The other would be storing the `Redis` credentials but I could just use `Secrets Manager` since I can poll `Secrets Manager` directly every time the `lambda` function is called.

Comment: OK, I see. Instead of Redis you should be using AWS built-in `SecretCache`. Check out the following AWS articles: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets_cache-python.html, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/retrieving-secrets.html

Comment: So you probably don't need to create a Lambda that will listen for a credentials update. Instead, you should create a Lambda that will handle the credentials rotation for you (as stated in this article: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/userguide/rotating-secrets.html). And your Flask app just uses the `SecretCache` for retrieving the credentials.